# When I connect to a VPN through Network Manager, DNS no longer works

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, vpn

When I connect to my 3rd party VPN service using the network manager, the DNS lookups no longer work. /etc/resolv.conf specifies 127.0.1.1 as nameserver which is dnsmasq service. However, I need to manually add a nameserver of 192.168.1.1 which is my router before my VPN traffic will flow. How do I fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 16

Comment: Depends on  a lot of things in particular if the VPN specifies a DNS server to use. Does the VPN add routes? Does it work for other users with a different VPN implementation (Windows, OSX)? And what type of VPN is this? openconnect? PPTP? Other?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Your question is about Ubuntu. You would probably get better expertise, and therefore better answers on Ask Ubuntu. Please flag your question to be migrated, or delete your question and re-ask it over there. Please do not cross-post (i.e. ask your question on Ask Ubuntu before you delete here or your question is migrated). You may ask your question there once you have deleted your question here.